# Scrunched Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following contrived view controller:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *l1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *l2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *input1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *input2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    for (UIView *view in @[self.l1, self.l2, self.input1, self.input2])
        [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSDictionary *views = @{ @"l1" : self.l1, @"l2" : self.l2,
                             @"input1": self.input1, @"input2" : self.input2,
                             @"topLayout" : self.topLayoutGuide};

    NSArray *constraints;
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[l1]-[input1]"
                                                          options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[l2]-[input2]"
                                                          options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    NSString *v1 = @"V:|-20-[input1]-[input2]";
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:v1
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    NSString *v2 = @"V:|-20-[l1]-[l2]";
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:v2
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}

@end
```

Which results in the following output:

[image]

If I simply change v1 and v2 to use the topLayoutGuide:

```
NSString *v1 = @"V:[topLayout]-20-[input1]-[input2]";
NSString *v2 = @"V:[topLayout]-20-[l1]-[l2]";
```

The screen looks all scrunched like this:

[image]

I can get this to go away when I stop using NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY on my horizontal constraints, but then my rows no longer line up properly:

[image]

Why is this issue occurring, and what would be the proper approach to get the rows to line up properly while still using the topLayoutGuide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, in a nutshell, is that you don't understand the relationship between the constraints generated by the storyboard/nib through auto layout and the constraints generated by your code. Your constraints were therefore *always* bad (even when the visual layout appeared to be correct). The problem with the top layout guide merely caused the badness of your constraints to become more visually obvious.

However, I would prefer not to belabor that point (i.e. all the stuff your code was doing wrong); I'd rather jump directly to the correct approach. Ready? Simply do as follows:

1. In your code, delete this line (which was in fact the cause of 90% of the trouble):

   ```
   [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
   ```
2. In the storyboard:

   a. Give all four elements (the two labels and the two text fields) *each* a left (leading) constraint and a top constraint.

   b. Select all eight of those constraints you just made and, in the Attributes inspector, check the box that says "Remove at build time".

Now your code will work exactly as you desire.

As I said, I'd rather not go on at length about why this is, but basically what I've instructed you to do is the correct way to create views in the storyboard/nib under autolayout and yet apply to those views only constraints generated in code.

---

Please note that you may also delete this line:

```
for (UIView *view in @[self.l1, self.l2, self.input1, self.input2])
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

It is doing no harm, but it is doing no good either, as these views *already* are not translating their autoresizing mask into constraints.

---

One final note: everything we've just done is extremely silly, since you *could* have taken one of two much more usual approaches:

- We could have generated all of those constraints *in the storyboard/nib* and simply deleted *all* your code.
- Or, just the opposite, we could have deleted the subviews from the storyboard/nib and created the subviews in code (and added them to `self.view` in code).

Either of those would have meant your code would have worked fine (except for the part about deleting all the constraints, which was always a disastrous idea). However, I showed you how to do what you were trying to do, simply for the sake of going along with the hypothesis.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. My eventual use case is indeed to create the subviews in code and rely on auto-layout to do the heavy lifting. I incorrectly thought that I could test out the basic concepts with a hastily created NIB. As you correctly point out, I did not fully understand the relationship between constraints generated by the storyboard/nib through auto layout and the constraints generated by my code.