# Programatically adding NSConstraints to existing views on storyboards

Tags: swift

i'm finding that constraints aren't implemented correcting when typed programatically to existing views on story boards. here's what i have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            textField2.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let superview = self.view

        let textField1 = UITextField()
        textField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        textField1.placeholder = "test text field"
        view.addSubview(textField1)
        textField1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.width * 0.50))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.height * 0.05))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.width * 0.50))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: superview.frame.height * 0.05))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        superview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField2, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    }
}
```

`textField1` works perfectly. it is add to the centre of the view. however, `textField2`, which i dragged and dropped onto the storyboard, is offset from the centre. why is this happening?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if a view comes from the storyboard, like your `textField2`, it *already has constraints*. Saying `textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` does not magically solve that problem. You would also need to get hold of those constraints, somehow, and remove them before applying your own constraints in code. That can be tricky to do, and *you* are *not* doing it, which is why your view is misbehaving. It is better, at this stage, for you to follow these simple rules:

- if a view comes from the storyboard, set its constraints only in the storyboard
- but if a view is made in code, now you can say `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and set its constraints in code

Comment: See also my answer to this question, which is actually exactly the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421925/scrunched-layout